# How to Make Ground Truth Images for Document Image Binarization Task?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, machine-learning

[image]

[image]

The two images are from DIBCO (Document Image Binarization Contest). The objective is to find a solution to binarize the top image (original image) to be similar to the bottom one (ground-truth image).

But if I want to make my own ground-truth image for my document image, how do I do it? Any idea, method, or technique is appreciated.

Comment: if just a few pairs of images would work, try to apply a simple binarization method and then polish the results manually

Comment: @MimSaad Polish image in pixel level is definitely nightmare, although I cannot think of any better method.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to remove the shadow from the image, and then apply global threshold method to binarize it.

Comment: @Ksiau, Could you review my answer?

Comment: Related to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62044.

Answer (score 0):

One technique is to imitate the degradation:

1. Create perfect images, like generating PDF programmatically.
   Those are your references.
2. Take each sample and degrade it by:

   - Noise.
   - Blurring.
   - Non uniform color manipulation.
   - Add shadows.

Then you can have samples with ground truth.