# Randomly Generate Synthetic Noise in an Image Text Document

Tags: noise, image-processing, random-process, random

I'm working on denoising dirty image document. I want to create a dataset wherein synthetic noise will be added to simulate real-world, messy artifacts. Simulated dirt may include coffee stains, faded sun spots, dog-eared pages, lot of wrinkles and many more. How shall I do that?

Sample Clean Image:

[image]

After adding Random Noise :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I randomly achieve images shown above?

Comment: How did you get the images above?

Comment: @Royi - It was from Kaggle Challenge. https://www.kaggle.com/c/denoising-dirty-documents/overview/description

Comment: I would say you need a generative model to generate those documents.

Comment: @Royi --> Can you link any research about generating images using genrative models?

Comment: Anything which has GAN or Variational Auto Encoders in it.